# LED array flashes once before being lit

Tags: arduino-uno, led, relay

I've built this simple Arduino controlled led-array. The Arduino sets a 5v pin on a relay to connect the high current power supply to a led array. 
However, just before the led array is being fully turned on I'm getting this fast flash of the led array. I really would like to have the led working in an "on/off" manner.

[image: Scheme]

I remember that working with some motors one have to use capcitator in parallel because of resistence drop. Is it also the case with led array? And if it is why so, and why a capcitator would help?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this flash only happen once each time the Arduino is 'booted'? If so, the issue may be the "power on" disposition of the Arduino pin that allow the LEDs to come on for a bit before the Arduinos pin is "configured".

Comment: Hi Wendeall,
No it happens every time to pin connected to the realy is set to "HIGH".

Comment: What led array are you using? What power supply are you using for this array?

Comment: The relay information shows this relay requires over 70ma to latch at 5 volts. The Arduino can only -maybe- provide half of that. Why it is working at all I don't know. Just as  Duncan C suggested, you are going to have to use a driver circuit (there are many designs, search for "Arduino relay driver") to correctly operate the relay. Then the "flash" will probably go away too.

Comment: Don't you use the matrix' SPI? If so, how do you know that it is supposed to work without, have you tried? Even if it's simple code you should add it, so we don't have to guess if there are mistakes. Also a link to the led matrix might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

As Wendall says in his comment, you probably have an issue with the power-on state of your logic pins before the Arduino finishes booting up.

In addition to that, you should **not** drive a relay directly from an Arduino logic pin, for a couple of reasons:

1. It can't provide enough current to drive a relay coil.
2. The relay emits a strong surge of reverse current when you switch it off. This will likely destroy the logic pin you are using to drive the relay, or it might even destroy the whole Arduino board.

For these reasons you should drive the relay using a transistor, and you should put a properly sized diode wired across the relay coil backwards from the flow of current when the relay is energized. The diode bleeds off the reverse current from the relay coil.

Comment: Thanks a lot Duncan. 

I'm using this relay:
http://www.circuitbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/SRD-05VDC-SL-C-Datasheet.pdf

Which suppose to be activated using a 5V pin. I would definitely try adding a diode to stop the reverse current.

However, the fast blink happens every time I close the relay circuit (turn on the led). There's one fast blink before the led is being activated.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you're using a "solid state relay", which has built-in circuitry to drive the relay coil from a low power logic line, while protecting the logic line from the "raw" relay. (If so it might have a transistor and protection diode in it already.) You might want to edit your question and post details on the type and setup of the relay you're using.